# Log4j java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, log4j

I couldnt understand what is causing this error:

```
ERROR>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator

ERROR>Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator
```

Already got the `log4j-1.2.8.jar` everywhere in the project but I couldnt make it. How can I make this error go away? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you haven't said what kind of application this is or basically given us *any* context. You need to make sure that the log4j classes are available to the classloader which is loading your application. If it's a standalone application run from the commandline, that's like to just be a case of specifying the `-classpath` command-line option. For example:

```
java -classpath .;log4j-1.2.8.jar org.foo.MyApplication
```

If you can give us more information, we're likely to be able to help you more.

Comment: I am upgrading to log4j 2. All jars are added in class path and jars are present in the lib folder as well.

Comment: @TusharBanne: That may well be a very different error. I suggest you ask a new question with all the relevant details.

Comment: Resolved the issue by adding a new jar file log4j-1.2-api-2.8.2.jar to the classpath. looks like even this jar is needed when migrating from log4j 1.X to log4j 2.

Answer (score 2):

Setp 1 : right click on your main method

Step 2 go to run as option then

Step 3 go to Run configuration

Step 4:  and add projects or jar files

now it works.

Comment: Where you added Jar?